# Why isn't my generated keystore file showing up?

Tags: codenameone, keystore, signing, jarsigner

I have generated my keystore file according to the Android Studio directions. When I tried to sign it using jarsigner, I ran into an error. I thought I could just skip this step and use my keystore file to generate an android build, but when I search for it, it isn't in the jdk bin where I created it. I tried to manually enter the keystore, but the build failed.

Error produced:
BUILD FAILED
C:\Eclipse451Mars64Workspace\App\build.xml:469: The file C:\Eclipse451Mars64Workspace\App\dist\App.jar exceeds 50MB in size! Please reduce the size of the project for faster builds and better performing apps.

Total time: 9 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Codename One tooling for keystore generation just right click the project and select Codename One -> CodenameOne Settings.

Then click "Android Certificate Generator".

Comment: Ok so I think i'm a little confused. I have a keystore generated now, but I'm still getting a build failure when I try to send my app to the build server. I thought I was getting this error because I was missing a keystore.

Comment: Press edit below your question and paste the full build error